Force clang-format to put multi-line arguments on the next line?
If clang-format finds it needs to put arguments on separate lines, I'd rather it put the first argument on the next line, rather than on the current one with subsequent arguments aligning to a random indent based on where the call happens.
I.e. currently I have this:
                irc_session->msg(channel,
                                 std::format("{} \"{}\" departing: {}",
                                             emoji,
                                             name,
                                             train.passengers));

...but I'd like this...
                irc_session->msg(
                        channel,
                        std::format(
                                "{} \"{}\" departing: {}",
                                emoji,
                                name,
                                train.passengers));

I've looked through the options but can't find how to specify this, is it possible?

The style option is https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#alignafteropenbracket
BracketAlignmentStyle: AlwaysBreak


BAS_AlwaysBreak (in configuration: AlwaysBreak) Always break after an open bracket, if the parameters don’t fit on a single line, e.g.:
someLongFunction(
     argument1, argument2);


